# Empty zip file when using JSZip and JSZipUtils with AngularJS to zip multiple image files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, zip, jszip

I'm trying to zip together multiple image files using JSZip and JSZipUtils with AngularJS.  I'm still fairly new to AngularJS, so I'm sure I've over complicated the process.  Please bear with me.

```
        vm.downloadDaughterZip = function (){
          var zip = new JSZip();
          vm.getBinaryContents(zip).then(function(result){
            vm.getZipImageFiles(result).then(function(data){
                saveAs(data, "daughters.zip");
            });
          });
        }

        vm.getBinaryContents = function (zip) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve(vm.getBinCont(zip, deferred));
          return deferred.promise;
        }

        vm.getBinCont = function (zip, deferred) {
          angular.forEach(vm.selectedDaughtersList, function (value, key){
            var tempPathArray = value.value.split('/');
            var filename = tempPathArray[tempPathArray.length -1];
            vm.getSingleBinaryContentCall(zip, value, filename, deferred);
          });
          return zip;
        }

        vm.getSingleBinaryContentCall = function (zip, value, filename, deferred) {
          deferred.resolve(vm.getSingleBinCont(zip, value, filename));
          return deferred.promise;
        }

        vm.getSingleBinCont = function (zip, value, filename) {
          JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(value.value, function (err, data){
            if(err){
                alert("some error");
            }
            else{
                zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true, compression : "DEFLATE"});
            }
          });
          return zip;
        }

        vm.getZipImageFiles = function (zip) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          deferred.resolve(vm.getImagesForZip(zip));
          return deferred.promise;
        }

        vm.getImagesForZip = function (zip) {
          console.log(zip);
          return zip.generate({type:"blob"});
        }
```

I'm trying to handle everything using promises to make sure that the files are being processed by JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent before trying to run zip.generate, then I make sure it's handling the zip.generate before using saveAs.

The good news is that when I look at the console log for the zip before I do the generate at the bottom, it seems to show the correct structure, including the image file data (which for some reason is being stored as type Uint8Array).  But when I run generate and pass it back up the stream to the saveAs call, the zip file it generates is empty.  The blob file that is being generated from zip.generate at the bottom appears to have no data when I do a console.log on it (only 22 bytes large).

My assumption is that either the image file format JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent generates is wrong and zip.generate isn't processing it correctly, or I'm still having some sort of timing issue.  The other side note is that the images are stored on the same server as the code, so I don't have to worry about cross-site issues.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

SOLVED!!!

So I looked at one of the examples on the JSZip page, and I cleaned this way up using their source code as an example.  I was over-complicating things, and it looks like there was some sort of timing issue because of it.  Here is the working code that I now have:

```
    vm.downloadDaughterZip = function (){
        var zip = new JSZip();
        var deferreds = [];

        angular.forEach(vm.selectedDaughtersList, function (value, key){
            var tempPathArray = value.value.split('/');
            var filename = tempPathArray[tempPathArray.length -1];
            deferreds.push(vm.getSingleBinCont(zip, value, filename));
        });
        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
            var blob = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
            saveAs(blob, "daughters.zip");
        });
    }

    vm.getSingleBinCont = function (zip, value, filename) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(value.value, function (err, data){
            if(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            else{
                zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    }
```